# Using Web2Py in Making a blog in Python (Google App Engine)? Is it a good Idea?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blogs, web2py

I know there are tons of blogging platforms out there (Wordpress,Drupal,etc) but I want to make my own blog engine or blog platform from scratch using python as a learning tool. The idea of using Google App Engine solves the issues in hosting. Blogs relatively consumes less amount of disk space and If it scales then there's no problem of migrations and other things related to that. I chose web2py as a framework cause I don't need to tweak the framework so that it would work with Google App Engine.

What do you think will the problems that I have to face in using GAE's Data Store? Will it be better if I use RDBMS instead of Google App Engine? What are the PROS and CONS if I use google app engine?

Comment: Google App Engine could be used, but it's designed more as a "big data" platform (i.e.: pushing around large chunks of data or doing some crazy processing). Check out Django, you can do some really cool stuff with it (SQLite, anybody?) and it'll scale like nobody's business.

Comment: Nick Johnson already wrote a blog engine for GAE. He also wrote a complete series (http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Writing-a-blog-system-on-App-Engine) of posts about it on his blog. IMO, writing an engine from scratch is quite a bit of work. You can probably learn as much by working through the posts and contributing a patch or two for issues (http://github.com/Arachnid/bloggart/issues).

Comment: @hwiechers +1 I came here to mention Nick's great example GAE/blog project

Answer (score 5):

You can use [this](http://www.vimeo.com/13485916?a) to build a blogging platform on Google App Engine with web2py. You may want to customize the layout using [this](http://web2py.com/layouts).

Comment: "This" will not be helpful if the link dies kindly put a name please

Answer (score 2):

Learning exercises, like the one you want to undertake, are just about the only good reason to reinvent the wheel -- and using a very lightweight framework can be more instructive than using a rich one such as Django, which does a lot for you under the covers.  As a very lightweight framework for GAE apps, I recommend [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/), but I guess tastes do differ;-).

The only real "pro" is that you'll learn a lot and learning is always a good thing.  The "con" is that it will take a lot of work that you could save by reusing existing blogging frameworks, but of course then you would miss out on a lot of the learning experience you're after!-)